# Modify JSON value & store it in the same object

Tags: jquery, json

It may sound silly but I am trying to modify a valid JSON object value based on some condition & update the old value with the new one. For some reasons, I am not able to share the exact data here but I have created a sample Fiddle here for reference.

can you please tell me what am I missing here?

```
var base = '{"abc":500}';
var json = $.parseJSON(base);
$('.json').text(base);
$.each(json, function(key, value){
    if(value < 1000){
        value = value * 1000;

    }
});
alert(JSON.stringify(json));
$('.updatedJson').text(JSON.stringify(json));
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/aalok/mc3ss8s1/)

Comment: try by use `json[key]= value * 1000`

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/mc3ss8s1/1/

Comment: Thanks guys! @mylee Can you post it in comments so that I can mark it as answer?

Comment: @AalokMishra run snippet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update current `json` object with `object[key] = value`

```js
var base = '{"abc":500}';
var json = $.parseJSON(base);
$('.json').text(base);
$.each(json, function(key, value){
 if(value < 1000){
  json[key] = value * 1000;
  
 }
});
alert(JSON.stringify(json));
$('.updatedJson').text(JSON.stringify(json));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="json">

</p>
<p class="updatedJson">

</p>
```